# Changing behaviour depending on packet type, avoiding switch statements

Tags: c++, inheritance, switch-statement, overloading

I'm writing a program with a server-client architecture that communicates primarily via packets. I'm having trouble coming up with a more eloquent way to achieve this.

Here's the kind of thing I have at the moment:

```
namespace Packet {    
    enum class TCP {
        PLAYER_JOINED,
        PLAYER_QUIT,
        MESSAGE_SENT
    };
}
```

Along with these functions to convert the types into integer codes and vice versa:

```
constexpr auto toInt(Packet::TCP _t) {
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Packet::TCP>>(_t);
}
constexpr Packet::TCP toTCPType(int _i) {
    return static_cast<Packet::TCP>(_i);
}
```

In my network manager code, I currently have an ugly switch statement that I want to avoid. Instead of it being like it currently is:

```
void sendPacket(Packet::TCP _type) {
    int code{Packet::toInt(_type);
    Packet p;
    p << code;

    switch (_type) {
        case Packet::TCP::PLAYER_JOINED:
            //do stuff and operate on p
            break;
        case Packet::TCP::PLAYER_QUIT:
            //do stuff and operate on p
            break;
        //etc.
    }
}
```

I would prefer if it could be something like this:

```
void preparePacket(Packet::TCP _type) {

    //common behaviour that has to be done no matter the type 
    int code{Packet::toInt(_type);
    Packet p;
    p << code;

    sendPacket(_type, p);
}
```

I'm running into several obstacles, though. Obviously I can't overload sendPacket on the value of the TCP enum. I could make each enumerator type its own struct, but then I lose the ability to quickly convert the Packets into an int, which is vital for the receiver to know what kind of packet it is. This can be solved by adding a virtual getId() function, but then that's only a one way conversion (Packet to int), whereas I also need to convert from int to Packet in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a vector of std::functions and use _type as index. At each index would be the function that handles that particular type of packet. Then your code could look something like this:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(Packet)>> handlers = { 
   player_joined_handler,
   player_quit_handler,
   message_sent_handler,
}
```

and then instead of the switch you could have this:

```
handlers[code](p);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent solution and just the kind of thing I was looking for.